# How many max. Simultaneous events watchdog (python) can handle?

Tags: python, events, watchdog

Below is the simple example of watchdog for move events. if we run this program and move 50 files in 'monitor' folder(mv *.xml monitor) then we received only 1 event. If we increase the queue size and timeout then the number of received events increased by 4 to 5 but its behavior is strange.

```
    observer = Observer(timeout=0.001)
    observer.event_queue.maxsize=100
```

can any one explain how to receive all the events. Thanks

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

class Myhandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_moved(self, event):
        print "Received evet:", event.dest_path

if __name__ == "__main__":
    event_handler = Myhandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path='monitor', recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Comment: If you are only printing inside the event, then everything should go fine, but if you are making or using some intensive function inside the events, you might miss the next ones when they are coming consecutively.

Comment: I tried your above example with 150 files moved to the monitor folder without adding the timeout or queue modifications. Things went very well.